# Second derivative in auto-parallel equation

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I am trying to derive the auto-parallel equation for a curve. Consider a smooth manifold $M$ with chart map $x$, and let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve in $M$.  The action of its tangent vector $v_{\gamma}$ (in the chart) on an arbitrary function $f$ is defined as $v_{\gamma} (f)$= $\frac{d}{d\lambda}((x\circ\gamma)^{i} )\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$. This motivates one to define $i$-th "component" of $v_\gamma$ in the chart $x$, $\dot \gamma^{i}_x$,   as $\dot \gamma^{i}_x=\frac{d}{d\lambda}((x\circ\gamma)^{i} )$.  Considering the above, can one show that
$\dot \gamma^{m}_x\frac{\partial \dot\gamma^q_x}{\partial x^m}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\dot \gamma^{q}_x ) = \ddot\gamma^{q}_x$?